# JSScript won't load on Xsplit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a script from an API server to display a specific value directly in my XSPLIT application.

After copying the script from the API URL, nothing is displayed in the '#activity' class.

I've tried to recreate output created from the source page by copying the script.

```
function UpdateGoal(){
        $.getJSON("https://api.tidylabs.stream/api/user.asp?key=GD6JC7FNBA3SBRZ0W9Z21542659578",function(json){ 
            var DonationValue = json.goaldonationvalue;
            var GraphPercentage = DonationValue/3500*100 + "%"
            $("#progress").css("width", GraphPercentage);
            $('.donationvalue').text(DonationValue);
            //console.log(FollowCount);
        });
    setTimeout(UpdateGoal, 8000);
}

UpdateGoal();


/* START TL ACTIVITY */
function UpdateActivity(){
    $('#activity').load('https://api.tidylabs.stream/api/activitycall.asp?key=GD6JC7FNBA3SBRZ0W9Z21542659578')
    setTimeout(UpdateActivity, 30000);
}
UpdateActivity();
```

Comment: For one, `#activity` isn't a selector for a class. The `#` is looking for an id... Is that the issue?

Comment: The second call (to `...activitycall.asp`) doesn't return anything. If nothing is returned from the call, nothing will be inserted into your element.